# How are impulse and Δp related?

Tags: forces, momentum

let,

Initial velocity $= u$

Final velocity $= v$

Acceleration $= a$

Mass $= m$

Momentum $= p$

Initial momentum $= mu$

Final momentum $= mv$

$$\frac{Δp}{Δt} = \frac{mv - mu}{Δt}$$

$$\frac{Δp}{Δt} = \frac{m(v - u)}{Δt}$$

$$\frac{Δp}{Δt} = ma \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$ $$= \mathrm{Force} $$

$$ \ \ \ Δp = \mathrm{Force} × Δt $$

$$ Δp \ \mathrm{(impulse)} = \mathrm{Force} × Δt \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   \tag1$$

---

$$ Δp = mv - mu $$

$$ Δp = m(v - u) \tag2 $$

---

In equation $(1)$ , we concluded that $Δp$ is force $\times$ change in time

In equation $(2)$, we concluded that $Δp$ is mass $\times$ change in velocity

**My question :** How are these two values for $Δp$ related after all?

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation (i) comes directly from Newton's 2nd Law, which was originally given as $F = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$.  Equation (ii) is the definition of $\Delta p$.  $\Delta p$ is impulse in both equations.